# How to utilize all vcores in R3 2X large 8 node cluster

Tags: performance, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit

My spark job is only using 32 Vcores out of 127 in total. Please refer to the image below.
[image: cluster_metrics]

My spark-submit command is: 
spark-submit --executor-memory 12G --num-executors 32  --executor-cores 3 --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=1.5g

How do I tweak spark-submit params to utilize all the resources available in the cluster.

Comment: Well, is there enough input data to actually need all of it?

Comment: There is one thing I noticed, no matter how much the data is, this value seems like it is equal to the number of executors(32 in this case). I wanted the job to speed up which is why I am tuning these params.

Comment: When you go to Spark UI, are your properties reflected there? For example, you've set 3 executor cores, so are they being used?

Comment: yes, all of them are being used...Turns out all I needed was more memory, when I changed from R3 2x to R4 4x my job ran twice as fast with same number of executors.